# Should we merge the "reference" and "resources" tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The tags [reference](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference) and [resources](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) seem to cover the same fields and be used by the same kinds of questions, and about half the time both tags are used on the same questions.

Vote to merge or clarify the difference...

Comment: Looking at the current list of questions for both, I'm not seeing any difference.